# How do I prove other funds in my bank account other than my salary?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I was refused UK visa recently because they could not verify the funds other than my salary. These funds were gifts sent to me by my mother and they were not large amounts. What can I do to rectify this in my reapplication?

Comment: Make sure there are no such deposits in any of the statements you have to provide when you re-apply. Will take a few months.

Comment: What kind of amounts were involved, how often, and how were they received (direct into your bank account from your mother’s account, or cash deposits)?

Comment: Some are direct . Some are sent from my mothers account  my mobile account and to my bank account. And they are as often as  every month.

Comment: Please review [this question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab).

Comment: You can provide your mother’s bank statements.