# do i need to add my statement when someone is sponsoring?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

My cousin in the Uk is sponsoring my visit , i will also be adding the bank statement of my mother that she supports me  . I work myself and will include my employment letter as proof. Do i need to add my personal bank statement ?

Comment: Please review [this question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab).

Comment: To what extent is your cousin in the UK sponsoring you? If they are providing any kind of financial support, you will need to provide their bank statements and proof of source of funds too.

Comment: I see from your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169365/how-do-i-prove-other-funds-in-my-bank-account-other-than-my-salary that you’ve already had a refusal. If you haven’t done so already, reading https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf and this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73404/uk-visitor-visa-refused-multiple-sponsors might help. Reapplying quickly after a refusal can be a big red flag for the ECO, especially if the premise of the new application differs from the original